# node.js でS3からイメージファイルを取得したいが、s3.getObject で　Forbidden 403 のエラーになる。

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws, amazon-s3

S3 にアップロードはできるのですが、node.jsで書いたサーバコードがgetObjectしてS3からファイルを取得しようと思ってるのですが403 Forbiddenエラーになります。

やりたいことはS3にアップロードした写真を読み込んで画面表示させたいのですが、肝心のS３からの画像の取得がうまくいきません。どなたかご教授願えたらと思っています。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

```
getImage: function(req, res) {
    var fileName = req.param('filename');
    sails.log.info('fileName = ' + fileName);
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
        region: 'ap-northeast-1'
    });

    var s3Params = {
        Bucket: コンスタントから取得したバケット名,
        Key: fileName
    };
    s3.getObject(s3Params, function (err, data) {
        if (err === null) {
            sails.log.info('ok!');
            res.send(data.Body);
        } else {
            sails.log.error('err = ' + err.message);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
},
```

S3のバケットポリシーは以下のように指定しています。

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReading",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/myusername"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: アップロードはできるという事ですので、PutObujectを許可しているバケットポリシーも書いていただけると何か分かるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

403 Forbiddenということは権限がないということなのでS3側で画像ファイルの設定を公開にしないと行けないかと思います。
S3での設定を一度ご確認してみるのがいいかと思います。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403